# How does number read/spelled as alphabet? ex: 213 as BAC. (jsp)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, calculator

I have  numbers , they are 213.
I want it encryption into alphabet, 213 into BAC. but when i ran the codes it didn't show anything.

here the codes .

Calculate.java // java servlet file

```
         String str = Integer.toString(numbers); 
        //it because numbers in int type, then i convert to string type first  before spelled
                   char[] alp;
                    alp = new char[str.length()];
             for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
                        if (str.charAt(i)=='1'){
                            alp[i]='a';
                        }else if(str.charAt(i)=='2'){
                         alp[i]='b';
                         }            
                        else if(str.charAt(i)=='3'){
                            alp[i]='c';
                                            }
                           else if(str.charAt(i)=='4'){
                         alp[i]='d';
                         }    
                          else if(str.charAt(i)=='5'){
                         alp[i]='e';
                         }   
                          else if(str.charAt(i)=='6'){
                         alp[i]='f';
                         }  
                          else if(str.charAt(i)=='7'){
                         alp[i]='g';
                         }   
                          else if(str.charAt(i)=='8'){
                         alp[i]='h';
                         }  
                          else if(str.charAt(i)=='9'){
                              alp[i]='i';
                          }
                          else if(str.charAt(i)=='0'){
                              alp[i]='j';
                          }
                        else{
                            alp[i]=str.charAt(i);
                        }
                    }

        out.println("<tr>");
                    out.println("<td>");
                    out.println("Convertion");
                    out.println("</td>");
                    out.println("<td>");
                    out.println(""+str+""); // print the output string "str" , what’s wrong with this? 
   // when i ran the codes, it didn't show anything.

                    out.println("</td>");
                   out.println("</tr>");

                }
```

thanks in advance :)

Comment: How did you run the codes? And yes, you would have to print the content of alp of course. But this should print something if wrapped inside a class and called properly.

Comment: i run on netbeans , java servlet

Answer (score 0):

You are storing converted character in alp[] array but you had printed str. So please print alp[] array and

Better way to do this using ascii code:
just pass each single number as integer to this function it will convert those numbers into characters and use those chars as you want

```
private String getCharForNumber(int i) {
   return i > 0 && i < 27 ? String.valueOf((char)(i + 64)) : null;
}
```

and print alp array as given below after closing first for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < alp.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("" + alp[i] + "");
    }
```

Comment: i code in java servlet (web application). cant put that void on. hehehe. but thanks for the answer, i will try